# Как вызвать метод класса из другого файла C++?

Tags: c++, классы, функции

Задача заключается в том, чтобы из отдельного файла/файлов вызвать функцию которая находится внутри класса.

```
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Func foo();

}
```

```
//Functions.cpp

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Functions.h"

using namespace std;
class Func
{
public:
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    };
private:

};
```

```
//Functions.h

#pragma once
#ifndef Functions_H
#define Functions_H



#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Func
{
public:
    void foo();
private:

};


#endif
```

Comment: объясните подробнее, у вас не получается подключить файл? создать экземпляр класса? вызвать функцию?

Comment: Ну и вызывайте. Класс, надеюсь, объявлен в заголовочном файле? Подключайте и вызывайте. Только не нарушайте правила доступа - ну, там, не вызывайте private откуда нельзя, например... :)

Comment: Файл подключен нормально, но проблема возникает с вызовом функции. Компилятор не ругается на код, но просто не выполняет ее.

Comment: Функция прописана в public

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: создайте обьект, вызывайте через обьект, а если статический метод, то вызывайте  с указанием квалификатора

Answer (score 5):

```
Func foo();
```

Это просто **объявление** функции `foo` без параметров, возвращающей объект типа `Func`. Понятно, что никакой код при этом не выполняется...

Если вы объявили в h-файле

```
class Func
{
public:
    void foo();
private:

};
```

то в .cpp, который включает этот h-файл, надо просто реализовать функцию, а не переписывать объявление еще раз. Кстати, что это за странный код?

```
class Func
{
public:
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    };
```

Надо:

```
void Func::foo()
{
        cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

Ну, а в `main` вызывать примерно так (например):

```
Func f;
f.foo();
```